# Heuristic to Use for A* with an Adjacency Matrix

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

I need to apply A* to an adjacency array. I understand how A* works and how a heuristic would work if I had an actual representation of my graph in 2d space, but am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around how I can create a heuristic that will work with an adjacency array, and haven't been able to find any resources online. Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

This WILL give you A 2d representation of the matrix but let me warn you that it is almost certainly not the best 2d representation. I encourage you to try to draw it out. If it is less than 50 or so vertices it wont take more than half an hour and it is probably worth it. If less than 20 it wont take 10 minutes.

http://graphonline.ru/en/create_graph_by_matrix

Comment: Do not answer just by posting a link.  Summarize the solution in your answer.